# Virtualbox + Vagrant corrupted static files issue

Tags: nginx, vagrant, virtualbox, uwsgi

There's a lot of people reporting issues with nginx and virtualbox. Solution that works for most seems to be using `sendfile off` in nginx config.
I've been experiencing similar problem with corrupted `js` and `css` files after updates. I tried switching `sendfile` to `off` in nginx config and restarting VM but this did not help. I decided to serve application through uwsgi only instead of uwsgi+nginx but the problem persisted.

In my case I have a Flask application that resides in host filesystem and is shared with VM to `/home/vagrant/appname`.
After doing some experimenting I found out that copying application files into VMs filesystem fixes the issue. This way code now actually resides in `/home/vagrant/appname`. 
I still don't know exactly what is causing this and preferably I would like the codebase to reside on host for easy editing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using uwsgi (no nginx) to develop my app in a Vagrant VM with VirtualBox 5.0.4 on OS X 10.10.5. I'm using shared folders, and just like you, I had issues with corrupted static files, i.e., .js. What did the trick for me was to add `--disable-sendfile` when I'm starting the app with uwsgi, e.g., :

`uwsgi --http IP:PORT -w app --disable-sendfile`